# How can I send a proxy request via request module with node.js

Tags: node.js, request

Here is my code:

```
  (function getComments(offset) {
    var options = {
      url: path + songId + '?limit=' + step + '&offset=' + offset,
      headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8'
      },
      proxy: '***.***.***.***:****',
    };

    Request.get(options, function (error, res, body) {
      if (!error && res.statusCode === 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);

        if (offset < data.total) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(offset);
            getComments(offset);
          }, Math.random() *2000 + 2000);
        } else {
          response.json(comments);
        }
      }
    });
  })(offset);
```

But my proxy didn't work, and I get an error when using `Request.get()` like `message: "Invalid protocol: 125.123.143.186:"`

Can anybody tell me how did that happen, and do I have a decent way to send a proxy request?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, most likely the reason of "Invalid protocol" error is that the URL, which you set in options object looks like this: `125.123.143.186:/some/path`. Check the path you are trying to hit, I'm pretty sure it is malformed, looks like you don't have a port after IP address. Due to the fact that URLs begin with the protocol and `://` combination, the URL parser of `Request` treats that IP address as a protocol, fails to validate it and then you get this error message.

Comment: It's really helpful. I add `http://` into proxy and it works. Thank you